# Is there any canonical support of a relationship between these two characters?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

In The Dark Knight Rises, it is revealed that

> Bane protected Talia al Ghul while imprisoned, that Bane was shunned by Ra's al Ghul from the League of Shadows. Furthermore, it was alluded to in the film that they could have been romantically involved.

Is there any canonical support for this, or is it merely a fabrication of the Nolan brothers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is canonical support for this - you just watched it. :)

The Batman trilogy is set in a different universe to the DC Comics, similar to Marvel except Marvel makes it explicit with their Earth-199999 and Earth-616 universes.  The former is the Marvel Cinematic Universe while the second is their standard comic universe.

I don't think DC has assigned an explicit universe to the various movies, as they are not trying to combine them all into one self-consistent universe (yet).  As such, each movie series has its own continuity.

To answer your question,

> this link between Talia and Bane is not prevalent in other DC versions of the legend, nor is Talia being born in a prison.

Comment: DC does have their 52 universes, but unlike Marvel, they don't assign various canons to a specific numbered universe until they make a step to actually integrate said canon into the greater multiverse.

Comment: The comic continuity had Ras Al-Ghul consider Bane as Talia's chosen mate, but she rejected him as just a brute compared to Batman, and eventually, Ras agrees: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talia_al_Ghul#Bane